# Restore MYSQL Dump File with Command Line

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have file.sql, and I want to restore it. I found this command:

`mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql`

Where should I put 'file.sql' in file system? I'm using Windows and XAMPP. Thank you.

*) The dump file is 3GB++

Comment: For me worked this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25724087/7809915.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I execute the answers of this thread, it returns `'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`.

Turned out that I have to execute mysql.exe first in xampp/mysql/bin folder, and the dump file path is relative to this bin folder. I put mine in there, and it worked.

Thanks all.

Comment: That's happening because you don't have mysql.exe in your Environment Variables. More info about MySQL import/export here: http://wpy.me/en/blog/2-how-to-export-and-import-a-mysql-database-from-the-command-line-shell

Answer (score 23):

You can put it anywhere, where there is enough diskspace available of course.

A good place for this would be either `/tmp` (on linux or similar) or `c:\temp` (on windows or similar)

But assuming you use that exact line you need to change your working directory to that which holds the file.

```
cd /path/where/sql/file/is
```

And then

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

If you don't have the mysql bin in your PATH you might want to run

```
/path/to/mysql/bin/mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

Or temporarily put the file.sql in the mysql bin directory (not recommended)

Another possible scenario is to point to the file in the filesystem like this

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < /path/where/sql/file/is/file.sql
```

PS. If you're on windows you might wanna change the forward slashes to backslashes.

Answer (score 6):

Type the following command to import sql data file:

```
$ mysql -u username -p -h localhost DATA-BASE-NAME < data.sql
```

In this example, import 'data.sql' file into 'blog' database using vivek as username:

```
$ mysql -u vivek -p -h localhost blog < data.sql
```

If you have a dedicated database server, replace localhost hostname with with actual server name or IP address as follows:

```
$ mysql -u username -p -h 202.54.1.10 databasename < data.sql
```

OR use hostname such as mysql.cyberciti.biz

```
$ mysql -u username -p -h mysql.cyberciti.biz database-name < data.sql
```

If you do not know the database name or database name is included in sql dump you can try out something as follows:

```
$ mysql -u username -p -h 202.54.1.10 < data.sql
```

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 5):

You can put anywhere in the system but consider to change the command also

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < /somepath/file.sql
```

Comment: getting this error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near"

Answer (score 3):

The best option will be

1) open the command prompt by Start -> Run -> Command or anyway
2) change you directory where the file.sql is saved say C:\temp\file.sql so your command prompt should look like

```
C:\temp>
```

3) now try these command

```
mysql -u root -p database_name < file.sql
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Import Database
1. Go to drive
command: d:
2. Mysql login
command: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -p
3. Will ask for pwd: enter it
pwd
4. Select db
use DbName;
5. Provide file name
\. G:DbName.sql
```

Comment: +1 I might recommend adding step 3.1 about `CREATE DATABASE DbName;` I'm not sure you can proceed with step 4 unless the DbName already exists. The only other tidbit I might add is the `--port 9999` _(where 9999 is YOUR specific port if MySQL is not on the default port of 3306 - mine isn't)._ If you are looking for a scripted solution, there are better answers here but doing it manually, this is spot on.

Answer (score 1):

you need to point to the location of your file using:

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < drive:\\path_to_your_file\file.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate, try to restore the dump with a Restore or with an Execute Large Script Wizard
Wizard.

There is a command-line support.

[Backup or restore](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-administration.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can restore the dump using phpmyadmin as well but you have to sure that it must be .sql file.

The second way is if you are linux user than use the command line to restore the dump file.

mysql> **mysql -uuser_name -ppassword table_name < /path/to/dump_file.sql**