# How to import an SQL file using the command line in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, import, command-line, dump

I have a `.sql` file with an export from `phpMyAdmin`. I want to import it into a different server using the command line.

I have a [Windows Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) R2 installation. I placed the `.sql` file on the ***C drive***, and I tried this command

```
database_name < file.sql
```

It is not working. I get syntax errors.

- How can I import this file without a problem?
- Do I need to create a database first?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restore MYSQL Dump File with Command Line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429748/restore-mysql-dump-file-with-command-line)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407349/mysql-how-to-export-and-import-an-sql-file-from-command-line

Comment: Whats with these duplicate guys? This indeed is a helpful question with its own purpose

Comment: @ValentinoPereira have you checked original question dates before determine duplicate guys

Comment: Can you share a reproducable example? `database < file.sql` does not look like any command to me, and if you see some syntax errors, please share them

Comment: After I have checked all answers below, I must say you missed a very important clue for those people who wants to help. You failed to specify the exact command when you dump data out of the database.

Comment: To import ***efficiently*** (200 times faster), see [Paresh Behede's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-do-i-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql/22855514#22855514).

Comment: "I  get syntax errors" - what does that mean?

Answer (score 4940, accepted):

Try:

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

Check [MySQL Options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html).

**Note 1:** It is better to use the full path of the SQL file `file.sql`.

**Note 2:** Use `-R` and `--triggers` with `mysqldump` to keep the routines and triggers of the original database. They are not copied by default.

**Note 3** You may have to create the (empty) database from MySQL if it doesn't exist already and the exported SQL doesn't contain `CREATE DATABASE` (exported with `--no-create-db` or `-n` option) before you can import it.

Comment: `sudo mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql` works in some cases.

Comment: So, `-R` and `--triggers` seem to be options for `mysqldump`, which wasn't immediately clear to me, based on the answer. Additionally, `--triggers` *is* enabled by default ["This option is enabled by default; disable it with `--skip-triggers`."](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_triggers)

Comment: What if I am using docker? :(

Comment: You can use `docker exec -i <container_id> mysql -u <user> --password=<password> database_name < file.sql` Reference: [Backup (and Restore) MySQL Data in Docker](https://makeshiftinsights.com/blog/backup-restore-docker-mysql-data/)

Answer (score 1045):

A common use of [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) is for making a backup of an entire database:

```
mysqldump db_name > backup-file.sql
```

You can load the dump file back into the server like this:

**Unix**

```
mysql db_name < backup-file.sql
```

The same in the **Windows** command prompt:

```
mysql -p -u [user] [database] < backup-file.sql
```

**[PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell)**

```
cmd.exe /c "mysql -u root -p db_name < backup-file.sql"
```

**MySQL command line**

```
mysql> use db_name;
mysql> source backup-file.sql;
```

Comment: Is it me only one who has never been able to use `<` operator in mysql? (ubuntu18/20)

Comment: No idea why the Windows examples include params `-u` and `-p` while the Unix example does not. The interface for `mysql` is the same on both, so most likely you need the same command in Unix as is presented here for Windows.

Comment: where we put backup-file.sql? what path it looks by default?

Comment: I go to C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin and run the mysql.exe. Login to MySQL and did the above changes. It worked. Thank you.

Comment: @StijndeWitt chances are that his linux distro has configured credentials in e.g. ~/.my.cnf file

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `source` command, so this was really helpful for me, esp when the SQL queries are so numerous that they can't be easily copy/pasted

Answer (score 505):

Regarding the time taken for importing huge files: most importantly, it takes more time because the default setting of MySQL is `autocommit = true`. You must set that off before importing your file and then check how import works like a gem.

You just need to do the following thing:

```
mysql> use db_name;

mysql> SET autocommit=0 ; source the_sql_file.sql ; COMMIT ;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do that in a single command line on the mysql command used for import?

Comment: Best answer inho. It was the `source` command I have forgotten.  Most of us want to do this while we _are_ logged in as standalone command among other commands, not the standard login>inject>logout oneliner  in top of google serps.

Comment: I agree that this is **the best answer**. The `autocommit=0` portion made a world of difference in terms of the speed.

Comment: will the `autocommit=0` will work on larger files? like 8gb sql file.

Comment: It's not always necessary to turn off `autocommit`. It's worth checking the database dump in an editor, it might already begin with `SET autocommit=0;`.

Comment: what about routines and triggers?

Comment: @Volomike { echo "SET autocommit=0;"; cat db.sql; echo "COMMIT;";} | mysql -u what -p - that's for posix-compliant command lines, not sure about windows

Comment: This works, and not only for huge files. For a particular (very simple) 5 megabyte SQL file with about 30,000 rows for the single table, it improved the import time from 31 minutes 35 seconds to 11 seconds. That is nearly ***200 times faster***!!!

Comment: For the sql path on windows, don't forget to use double backslash such as `C:\\Users\\soner\\Desktop\\file.sql`

Comment: how would you do this when importing to a new server where the files are creating the db as part of the import process?  since the db doesn't yet exist, how can you turn of autocommit during import?

Comment: `mysql -e "SET autocommit=0; SOURCE /build/dev-dump.sql; COMMIT;"` and `mysql -e "SOURCE /build/dev-dump.sql"` had really no difference for me in MariaDB 10.6.16 - one took 1m26 and the other, 1m24.

Answer (score 97):

We can use this command to import SQL from the command line:

```
mysql -u username -p password db_name < file.sql
```

For example, if the username is `root` and password is `password`. And you have a database name as `bank` and the SQL file is `bank.sql`. Then, simply do like this:

```
mysql -u root -p password bank < bank.sql
```

Remember where your SQL file is. If your SQL file is in the `Desktop` folder/directory then go the desktop directory and enter the command like this:

```
cd ~/Desktop
mysql -u root -p password bank < bank.sql
```

And if you are in the `Project` directory and your SQL file is in the `Desktop` directory. If you want to access it from the `Project` directory then you can do like this:

```
cd ~/Project
mysql -u root -p password bank < ~/Desktop/bank.sql
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a space between `-p` and `password`

Comment: Jap. This would not work. Correct would be `mysql -u root -p"password" bank < bank.sql`

Comment: why you simply can't answer in one line?  `mysql -u username -ppassword db_name < file.sql`

Comment: while this is completely unrelated to this question/answer, when you're working with non-trivial databases, prefer NOT entering the password on the same command in plain text. Not specifying the password as part of the command will prompt you for password which you can enter securely

Comment: Especially because of `.bash_history`

Comment: I agree. Anycase in mysql 8.0 is possile to do this: [Disabling Interactive History](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tips.html#mysql-history) :  mysql supports disabling the interactive history partially or fully, depending on the host platform.

Comment: not just because of `.bash_history`, but also because anyone with the ability to view your running command line (via `/proc` or `ps`, etc) can see the password you entered. just say no to command line passwords

Comment: keeping the -p empty and putting a -D before the database name, it will ask for your password after you press enter, and your password won't be visible, nor on screen nor in your bash history. Like your example: `mysql -u root -p -D bank < ~/Desktop/bank.sql`

Comment: @Eyso What is `-D` for?

Comment: @HashimAziz It is for selecting a database (in this case, 'bank'); If you have exported the whole database system (multiple databases) in the .sql file, this merely prevents using the content of the .sql file as password.

Answer (score 77):

If you already have the database, use the following to import the `dump` or the `sql` file:

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

if you don't you need to create the relevant database(empty) in MySQL, for that first log on to  the `MySQL` console by running the following command in terminal or in cmd

```
mysql -u userName -p;
```

And when prompted provide the password.

Next, create a database and use it:

```
mysql>create database yourDatabaseName;
mysql>use yourDatabaseName;
```

Then import the `sql` or the `dump` file to the database from

```
mysql> source pathToYourSQLFile;
```

Note: if your terminal is not in the location where the `dump` or `sql` file exists, use the relative path in above.

Answer (score 68):

1. Open the MySQL command line
2. Type the path of your mysql bin directory and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Paste your SQL file inside the `bin` folder of mysql server.
4. Create a database in MySQL.
5. Use that particular database where you want to import the SQL file.
6. Type `source databasefilename.sql` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>
7. Your SQL file upload successfully.

Comment: ype the path of your mysql bin directory and press

Answer (score 54):

A solution that worked for me is below:

```
Use your_database_name;
SOURCE path_to_db_sql_file_on_your_local;
```

Comment: This worked for me using MySQL Command Line Client, after placing my sql file in the proper /bin directory view windows explorer.  Thanks

Comment: Little slow but does not stop in between and don't say that MySQL server has gone away.

Answer (score 48):

While most answers here just mention the simple command

> mysql -u database_user -p [db_name] < database_file.sql

today it's quite common that databases and tables have utf8-collation where this command is not sufficient.
**Having utf8-collation in the exported tables it's required to use this command:**

```
mysql -u database_user -p  --default-character-set=utf8 [db_name] < database_file.sql
```

An according export can be done with

```
mysqldump -u database_user -p --default-character-set=utf8 [db_name] > database_file.sql
```

Surely this works for other charsets too, how to show the right notation can be seen here:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-collation.html

One comment mentioned also that if a database never exists an empty database had to be created first. This might be right in some cases but depends on the export file. If the exported file includes already the command to create the database then the database never has to be created in a separate step, which even could cause an error on import. So on import, it's advisable to have a look first in the file to know which commands are included there, on export, it's advisable to note the settings, especially if the file is very large and hard to read in an editor.

There are still more parameters for the command which are listed and explained here:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html

**If you use another database version consider searching for the corresponding version of the manual too. The mentioned links refer to MySQL version 5.7.**

**EDIT:**
The same parameters are working for `mysqldump` too. So while the commands for export and import are different, the mentioned parameters are not.
Nevertheless there exists a special site in the manual that describes the options for `mysqldump`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 47):

To dump a database into an SQL file use the following command.

```
mysqldump -u username -p database_name > database_name.sql
```

To import an SQL file into a database (make sure you are in the same directory as the SQL file or supply the full path to the file), do:

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < database_name.sql
```

Answer (score 45):

I think it's worth mentioning that you can also load a **gzipped (compressed)** file with `zcat` like shown below:

```sh
zcat database_file.sql.gz | mysql -u username -p -h localhost database_name
```

Comment: On macOS, I had to use `gzcat` instead of `zcat`.

Answer (score 42):

Go to the directory where you have the MySQL executable. `-u` for username and `-p` to prompt for the password:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -u username -ppassword databasename < C:\file.sql
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further questions, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Comment: That would work only if you have mysql.exe defined in your windows environment variables. If not, you should type all the path to the mysql.exe file. And Your syntax is wrong. Eg: "d:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\bin\mysql.exe -u YOUR_USERNAME -p DB_NAME < FILENAME.SQL" More info here: http://wpy.me/en/blog/2-how-to-export-and-import-a-mysql-database-from-the-command-line-shell

Comment: D:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -u root -p  opfedu_campuses < C:\Users\Raham\Desktop\opfedu_campuses.sql

Answer (score 39):

To import a database, use the following command.

```
mysql> create new_database;
mysql> use new_database;
mysql> source (Here you need to import the path of the SQL file);

E.g.:
mysql> source E:/test/dump.sql;
```

You need to use forward slashes (/) even on Windows, e.g., *E:/test/dump.sql* instead of *E:\test\dump.sql*

Or double backslashes (\\) because of escaping, i.e., *E:\\test\\dump.sql*

Comment: This actually worked for me. The suggestion with 4000+ votes didn't.

Comment: You need to use forward slashes (/) even on Windows, e.g. E:/test/dump.sql instead of E:\test\dump.sql

or double backslashes (\\\) because of escaping, i.e. E:\\test\\dump.sql

Comment: But this is not from the command line in the spirit of the question. It is using the MySQL shell interactively.

Comment: `source` is not intended for importing databases, but rather for running a small number of SQL queries. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6163842

Answer (score 36):

To import a single database, use the following command.

```
mysql -u username -p password dbname < dump.sql
```

To import multiple database dumps, use the following command.

```
mysql -u username -p password < dump.sql
```

Comment: Thanks!
I was looking for this. Importing all MySQL database dumps at once.
A more concise and short version of the above command

mysql -u root -p < all.sql

Answer (score 24):

```
mysql --user=[user] --password=[password] [database] < news_ml_all.sql
```

Answer (score 23):

I kept running into the problem where the database wasn't created.

I fixed it like this:

```
mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE db_name"
mysql db_name --force < import_script.sql
```

Comment: What's the need to have `--force` here?

Answer (score 20):

For importing multiple SQL files at one time, use this:

```
# Unix-based solution
for i in *.sql ; do mysql -u root -pPassword DataBase < $i ; done
```

For simple importing:

```
# Unix-based solution
mysql -u root -pPassword DataBase < data.sql
```

For [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP):

```
REM mysqlVersion - replace with your own version
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlVersion\bin\mysql.exe -u root -pPassword DataBase < data.sql
```

For XAMPP:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -pPassword DataBase < data.sql
```

Answer (score 20):

For exporting a database:

```
mysqldump -u username -p database_name > file.sql
```

For importing a database:

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

Answer (score 18):

You do not need to specify the name of the database on the command line if the .sql file contains `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db_name` and `USE db_name` statements.

Just make sure you are connecting with a user that has the permissions to create the database, if the database mentioned in the .sql file does not exist.

Answer (score 17):

#### Import a database

1. Go to drive:

   ```
    d:
   ```
2. MySQL login

   ```
    c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -p
   ```
3. It will ask for pwd. Enter it:

   ```
    pwd
   ```
4. Select the database

   ```
    use DbName;
   ```
5. Provide the file name

   ```
    \.DbName.sql
   ```

Comment: On Windows, presumably? Why is it necessary to change to drive `D:`? Is file `DbName.sql` presumed to be at the root of drive `D:`? Can you elaborate? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25051722/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 17):

Use:

```
mysql -u root -p password -D database_name << import.sql
```

Use the MySQL help for details - `mysql --help`.

I think these will be useful options in our context:

```
[~]$ mysql --help
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, for osx10.12 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?
  --bind-address=name IP address to bind to.
  -D, --database=name Database to use.
  --delimiter=name    Delimiter to be used.
  --default-character-set=name Set the default character set.
  -f, --force         Continue even if we get an SQL error.
  -p, --password[=name] Password to use when connecting to server.
  -h, --host=name     Connect to host.
  -P, --port=#        Port number to use for connection or 0 for default to, in order of preference, my.cnf, $MYSQL_TCP_PORT, /etc/services, built-in default (3306).
  --protocol=name     The protocol to use for connection (tcp, socket, pipe,
  -s, --silent        Be more silent. Print results with a tab as separator, each row on new line.
  -v, --verbose       Write more. (-v -v -v gives the table output format).
  -V, --version       Output version information and exit.
  -w, --wait          Wait and retry if connection is down.
```

What is fun, if we are importing a large database and not having a progress bar. Use Pipe Viewer and see the data transfer through the pipe

For Mac, `brew install pv`

For Debian/Ubuntu, `apt-get install pv`.

For others, refer to *[pv - Pipe Viewer](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml)*

```
pv import.sql | mysql -u root -p password -D database_name

1.45GiB 1:50:07 [339.0KiB/s]   [=============>      ] 14% ETA 11:09:36
1.46GiB 1:50:14 [ 246KiB/s]     [=============>      ] 14% ETA 11:09:15
1.47GiB 1:53:00 [ 385KiB/s]     [=============>      ] 14% ETA 11:05:36
```

Comment: For Centos: `yum install pv`

Comment: There should be no space between "-p password" the command should be like

"mysql -u username -ppassword dbname < sqlfile" else
"mysql -u username -p db < sqlfile" this will prompt for password

Answer (score 11):

Go to the directory where you have MySQL.

```
 c:\mysql\bin\> mysql -u username -p password database_name <
 filename.sql
```

Also to dump all databases, use the `-all-databases` option, and no databases’ name needs to be specified anymore.

```
mysqldump -u username -ppassword –all-databases > dump.sql
```

Or you can use some GUI clients like SQLyog to do this.

Comment: Does it work with the strange dash (–)  - near *"all-databases"* (also in the first revision)?

Answer (score 11):

You can try this query.

Export:

```
mysqldump -u username –-password=your_password database_name > file.sql
```

Import:

```
mysql -u username –-password=your_password database_name < file.sql
```

and detail following this link:

https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/importing-from-and-exporting-to-files-using-the-mysql-command-line/

Answer (score 9):

Add the [`--force` option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_force):

```
mysql -u username -p database_name --force < file.sql
```

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes the port defined as well as the server [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) of that database also matters...

```
mysql -u user -p user -h <Server IP address> -P<port> (DBNAME) < DB.sql
```

Answer (score 8):

The following command works for me from the command line (cmd) on 
Windows 7 on [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP).

```
d:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/bin/mysql.exe -u root -p db_name < database.sql
```

Answer (score 8):

Providing credentials on the command line is not a good idea. The above answers are great, but neglect to mention

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file=etc/myhost.cnf database_name < file.sql
```

Where etc/myhost.cnf is a file that contains host, user, password, and you avoid exposing the password on the command line. Here is a sample,

```
[client]
host=hostname.domainname
user=dbusername
password=dbpassword
```

Comment: Command-line is volatile though (and unless you have a keylogger or a man-behind-your-back I'd expect it to be safe when executed locally), whereas a file is permanent, thus should be a higher risk, esp. when it is in plain text

Comment: ...however, the mysql command does indeed warn "mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure."

Answer (score 8):

Similarly to [vladkras's answer to *How do import an SQL file using the command line in MySQL?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-do-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql/17666285#17666285).

Key differences for me:

1. The database has to exist first
2. No space between `-p` and the password

---

```
shell> mysql -u root -ppassword #note: no space between -p and password
mysql> CREATE DATABASE databasename;
mysql> using databasename;
mysql> source /path/to/backup.sql
```

I am running Fedora 26 with MariaDB.

Comment: But this is not from the command line in the spirit of the question. It is using the MySQL shell interactively.

Answer (score 8):

**Import into the database:**

> mysql -u username -p database_name  <  /file path/file_name.sql

**Export from the database:**

> mysqldump -u username -p database_name   >  /file path/file_name.sql

After these commands, a prompt will ask for your MySQL password.

Answer (score 7):

I thought it could be useful for those who are using [Mac OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X):

```
/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin/mysql -u root -p database < database.sql
```

Replace `xampp` with `mamp` or other web servers.

Answer (score 7):

For information, I just had the default root + without password. It didn't work with all previous answers.

- I created a new user with all privileges and a password. It worked.
- -ppassword WITHOUT SPACE.

Answer (score 6):

For backup purposes, make a BAT file and run this BAT file using [Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler). It will take a backup of the database; just copy the following line and paste in [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) and then save the .bat file, and run it on your system.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1" %%i in ('date /t') do set DATE_DOW=%%i
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('date /t') do set DATE_DAY=%%i
for /f %%i in ('echo %date_day:/=-%') do set DATE_DAY=%%i
for /f %%i in ('time /t') do set DATE_TIME=%%i
for /f %%i in ('echo %date_time::=-%') do set DATE_TIME=%%i

"C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql server 5.5\bin\mysqldump" -u username -ppassword mysql>C:/%DATE_DAY%_%DATE_TIME%_database.sql
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Windows 10 with PowerShell 5 and I found almost all "Unix-like" solutions not working for me.

```
> mysql -u[username] [database-name] < my-database.sql
At line:1 char:31
+ mysql -u[username] [database-name] < my-database.sql
+                               ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported
```

I ends up using this command:

```
> type my-database.sql | mysql -u[username] -h[localhost] -p [database-name]
```

And it works perfectly, and hopefully it helps.

Thanks to @[Francesco Casula](https://stackoverflow.com/users/828366/francesco-casula)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39125080/881743), BTW.

Answer (score 4):

The following steps help to upload `file.sql` to the MySQL database.

Step 1: Upload `file.sql.zip` to any directory and unzip there 
**Note**: `sudo apt-get install unzip`
: `sudo apt-get unzip file.sql.zip`
Step 2: Now navigate to that directory. Example: `cd /var/www/html`

Step 3: `mysql -u username -p database-name < file.sql`
 
         Enter the password and wait till uploading is completed.

Answer (score 4):

If importing data into a Docker container use the following command. Adjust user(-u), database(-D), port(-P) and host(-h) to fit your configuration.

```
mysql -u root -D database_name -P 4406 -h localhost --protocol=tcp -p < sample_dump.sql
```

Comment: I needed the host name to mention because localhost was not the DB host name in my case. So this syntax helped me. Voting it up.

Answer (score 4):

#### To import a database via the terminal

Navigate to folder where the .sql file is located

Then run the below command:

```
mysql -u database_user_name -p database_name < sql_file_name.sql
```

It will ask for a password. Enter the database password. It will take a few seconds to import the data into the database.

Answer (score 4):

This line imports the dump file in the local database, under Linux.

```
mysql -u dbuser -p'password including spaces' dbname < path/to/dump_file.sql
```

This line imports the dump file in the remote database, under Linux. Note: `-P` is for the port and is required if the MySQL port is different than the default.

```
mysql -h dbhost -u dbuser -p'password including spaces' -P 3306 dbname < path/to/dump_file.sql
```

Note: the password includes spaces and this is the reason of the single quotes. Just change the path style for using the command under Windows (`C:\windows\path\dump_file.sql`).

Answer (score 4):

Using MySQL Secure Shell:

```
mysqlsh -u <username> -p -h <host> -D <database name> -f dump.sql
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use **XAMPP** on the windows, first, you must manually create the database and then run the following commands:

```sh
cd C:\xampp\mysql\bin && 
mysql -u YOUR_USERNAME -p YOUR_DATABASE_NAME < PATH_TO_YOUR_SQL_FILE\YOUR_SQL_FILE.sql
```

And then enter the password

Answer (score 3):

```
mysql -u myuser -p mydatabase < mydata.sql
```

Replace `myuser` with your MySQL username, `mydatabase` with the name of your MySQL database, and `mydata.sql` with the name of your SQL file.
Make sure that the SQL file is properly formatted and does not contain any syntax errors that could cause issues during import.

Answer (score 3):

For example, you export the schema and data or only the schema of the tables of `apple` database to `backup.sql` with [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/export-mysql-dump-from-command-line/77363989#77363989) explains how to export the schema and data of the tables of a database:

```
mysqldump -u john -p apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -d apple > backup.sql
```

Or, you export only the data of the specific tables `person` and `animal` of `apple` database to `backup.sql` with [INSERT statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) which has column names as shown below. *By default, `INSERT` statement doesn't have column names and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109993/dump-only-the-data-with-mysqldump-without-any-table-information/77371448#77371448) explains how to export only data more:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -t -c apple person animal > backup.sql
```

Then, you need to input a password after running the command above:

```
Enter password:
```

Now, you can import `backup.sql` into `orange` database with [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html) as shown below. *When importing the schema and data or only the schema, selected `orange` database must exist and when importing only the data, selected `orange` database and the tables must exist otherwise there is error and when importing only the data, you need to delete all the data from apple database otherwise there will be error. [The documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/reloading-sql-format-dumps.html) explains how to import databases and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428416/how-to-create-a-database-from-shell-command-in-mysql#77338484) explains how to create a database:

```
mysql -u john -p orange < backup.sql
```

Or:

```
mysql -u john -p -D orange < backup.sql
```

Or:

```
mysql -u john -p --database orange < backup.sql
```

Then, you need to input a password after running the command above:

```
Enter password:
```

Or, after login, you can import `backup.sql` into `orange` database with `\.` or `source` selecting `orange` database as shown below:

```
mysql -u john -p
...
mysql> USE orange;
mysql> \. backup.sql
```

Or:

```
mysql -u john -p
...
mysql> USE orange;
mysql> source backup.sql
```

Be careful, you cannot import `backup.sql` into `orange` database not selecting `orange` database as shown below:

So, this below gets error:

```
mysql -u john -p < backup.sql
```

> ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 22: No database selected

And, these below get error:

```
mysql -u john -p
...
mysql> \. backup.sql
```

Or:

```
mysql -u john -p
...
mysql> source backup.sql
```

> ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected

In addition, you can import `backup.sql` into `orange` database without a password prompt by setting a password(e.g., `banana`) to [-p(--password=)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_password) as shown below. *Don't put any space just after `-p`(`--password=`) because there is error and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293042/how-to-perform-a-mysqldump-without-a-password-prompt/77467506#77467506) explains how to import a database without a password prompt in detail:

```
mysql -u john -pbanana orange < backup.sql
```

Comment: Are the two asterisks intentional?

Answer (score 2):

For Windows OS, you can use the below command to import data from an SQL dump.

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>mysql -u<> -p<> DBName < filelocation\query.sql

Where `-u` is the username, and `-p` is the MySQL password. Then enter your password and wait for data to import.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
mysql -u<user> -p<pass> <db> < db.sql
```

Example:

```
mysql -uroot -proot db < db.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

- Create a database in MySQL.
- Then go to your computer directory *C:\xampp\mysql\bin*, write `cmd` in the address bar, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Unzip your SQL file
- Then write: `mysql -u root -p dbname` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Write: source sql.file. Like `Source C:\xampp\htdocs\amarbazarltd\st1159.sql`
- Done

Comment: Upvote for the Windows trick of getting cmd to open in the correct directory.

Comment: Re *"go to your computer directory"*: Do you mean in [File Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes File Explorer

Answer (score 2):

Simple. Just use this command in cmd:

```
use databasename
\. C:/test/data.mysql
```

Comment: There [isn't a "`use`" in cmd](https://ss64.com/nt/) (Windows) as far as I know (though there is [`NET USE`](https://ss64.com/nt/net-use.html)). Do you mean inside the MySQL client? Or something else? Can you elaborate? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65153385/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [MAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAMP) on Mac OS X, this may be helpful:

```
/applications/MAMP/library/bin/mysql -u MYSQL_USER -p DATABASE_NAME < path/to/database_sql/FILE.sql
```

MYSQL_USER is root by default.

Answer (score 1):

If your folder has multiple SQL files, and you've installed [Git Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807485) you can use this command to import multiple files:

```
cd /my-project/data

cat *.sql | /c/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p 1234 myProjectDbName
```

Answer (score 1):

Export particular databases:

```
mysqldump --user=root --host=localhost --port=3306 --password=test -B CCR KIT > ccr_kit_local.sql
```

This will export CCR and KIT databases...

Import all exported databases to a particular MySQL instance (you have to be where your dump file is):

```
mysql --user=root --host=localhost --port=3306 --password=test < ccr_kit_local.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are importing to your local database server, you can do the following:

```
mysql -u database_user -p < database_file.sql
```

For a remote database server do the follwing:

```
mysql -u database_user -p -h remote_server_url < database_file.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Ubuntu**

```
 mysql -u root -p
 CREATE database dbname;
 use dbname;
 source /home/computername/Downloads/merchantapp.sql
 exit;
```

**In Windows**

Download the SQL file and save it in `C:\xampp\mysql\bin`.

After that, open the command prompt with `C:\xampp\mysql\bin`:

```
 C:\xampp\mysql\bin> mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

Comment: But this is not from the command line in the spirit of the question. It is using the MySQL shell interactively.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) then go to folder `xappp` → `mysql` → `bin`. Open cmd here and paste this:

```
mysql -u root -p dbname < dbfilename.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these steps as easily.

1. Download the SQL file into your "mysql/bin" folder.
2. Open the "mysql/bin" folder using CMD.
3. If not exists required database, then create the database first.
4. Type this in the CMD and run:

   `mysql -u <user> -p<password> <dbname> < file.sql`

   "file.sql"  is an SQL file that you want to insert into the target database.
   examples:
   If your "password" is "1234", "user" is "root", and "dbname" is "test":

   ```
    mysql -u root -p1234 test < file.sql
   ```

   If your "password" is null & "user" is "root" & "dbname" is "test"

   ```
    mysql -u root test < file.sql
   ```
5. Check the target data successfully uploaded or not.

This method can be used to upload the large size data using SQL files in the CMD.

Make sure in step 4, if you use that password, insert "-p" as a single word without any spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers include > or < characters which is not a proper method for all the cases. I recommend using **mysqlimport** while you may make the dump file using **mysqldump**.

[These tools](https://mysqldump.guru/how-to-install-and-run-mysqldump.html) will be installed with the mysql service and both are available for backup and restore in a database or multiple databases in MySQL.

Here is the way you could leverage it for importing to the mysql

> mysqlimport -u database_admin -p database_name ~/path/to/dump_file.sql

In case you do not have it, please install it via:

> sudo apt update
> sudo apt install mysql-client

In the same way, you make a backup to a dump file as [follows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html):

> mysqldump [options] --result-file=dump_file.sql

Answer (score 0):

## The fastest way

I've used the solution below to import a 100GB database (not a typo) of almost 300 million records in less than 10 hours, so it's safe to say it will rip through the average SQL dump in no time.

First, you should make sure your database is making the most of your hardware - most out-of-the-box SQL installations are set up to be as lightweight (and therefore inefficient) as possible. Assuming your database is using the InnoDB engine (which it is if you are using XAMPP), edit the following variables in your `my.ini` file:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8G // Change to 50-75% of your system's RAM, depending on how much you need to keep free
innodb_log_file_size=2G // Change to 25% of the above value
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
```

If you're using another database engine then you'll need to find the equivalent configuration options and tune them accordingly.

Once you've made those configuration changes, restart your server and run the following in the command-line:

```
mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS <database_name>; USE <database_name>; \
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0; SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0; \
source <file_name>; SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 1; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1; COMMIT;"
```

Although this uses the `mysql` CLI tool it's just executing plain MySQL so you can alternatively copy-paste the SQL code from it directly into your database tool's SQL tab (eg. PHPMyAdmin).

Answer (score 0):

```
USE yourdb; // Database name  

SOURCE D:/your folder path/Folder/filetoimport.sql;
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer, please? Thanks in advance. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77599079/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: What if there are spaces in the SQL file path?

Answer (score -1):

1. copy the database file to *C:\xampp\mysql\bin*
2. open a terminal from the same path
3. type in the terminal

   ```
    .\mysql.exe -uroot
   ```
4. type `use DB_NAME;` // Change to your DB Name
5. type `source DB_FILE.sql;`

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
cd C:\xampp\mysql\bin
mysql -u root -p database_name --force < C:\file.sql
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer - why did the given call resolve syntax errors?

Answer (score -4):

1. Go to your `wamp` or `xampp` directory

   Example

   ```
   cd d:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.24/bin
   ```
2. `mysql -u root -p  DATABASENAME < PATHYOUDATABASE_FILE`