# MySQL: How to import a sql dump.. inside mysql command line?

Tags: mysql, sql

I often keep a shell open to a remote server where I'm spending a lot of time in mysql. Exiting mysql and logging back in seems like a pain I shouldn't have to deal with if I just want to run a sql file.

**When I'm running MySql from the command line, how can I run a dump file?**

Right now, I'm using the same approach [outlined in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-a-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql#17666279).

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> use db_name;
mysql> source backup-file.sql;
```

You may want to take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17666285