# execute .sql file using command line

Tags: mysql, linux, command-line

I am trying to run a sql file located at /desktop/folder/query.sql in command line.
I have the database changed to the one that I need but am unsure how to execute the file. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What is the problem with using [MySQL-Doc: Executing SQL Statements from a Text File](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-batch-commands.html)?

Comment: I seem to be getting an error when trying to specify a directory /desktop/folder/query.sql. The server is remote with the file being local on my machine

Comment: Just solved it. mysql> source desktop/folder/query.sql

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import an SQL file using the command line in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql)

Answer (score 5):

answering my own question,

```
mysql> source desktop/folder/query.sql;
```

Just had to use the 'source' prefix.

Comment: Which is where i found it. Thanks for the link, and the downvote