# Import MySQL dump file returns nothing

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

i have a dump file that i am trying to import

```
mysql> use somedb_dec6; 
mysql> source somedump_nov29.sql
```

However when i do `show tables;` immediately it is showing me the correct tables, but if i get out of mysql prompt and login again and see what is in the database it shows me the following

```
mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Why is mysql not able to source the dump file?
Thanks

as per request this is the dump file content

```
-- MySQL dump 10.11
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: some_test
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.0.77

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Current Database: `some_test`
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant contents of the `somedump_nov29.sql` script file?  Is it possible that it just creating temporary tables which then vanish when your user session ends?

Comment: also run `SELECT DATABASE()` after importing sql. You might be moved to another DB by somedump_nov29.sql.

Comment: hey actually i am attempting to make a copy of another db. So @TimBiegeleisen yes you are right the tables vanish after the session ends,

Comment: Show us the relevant portions of the scripts.  Whatever it is you are trying to do is not "sticking."  We need to make it stick.

Comment: and the contents of the .sql file is a large dump file with data of the original db

Comment: What do you mean by relevant portions of script? like initial part of the .sql file?

Comment: hey @TimBiegeleisen, please find the edit in the question

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have access to terminal, can import like this:

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

Note: It is better to use the full path of the SQL file `file.sql`.

[original answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql) || [excellent guide here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-import-and-export-databases-and-reset-a-root-password-in-mysql)

`source` is seen more in execute an SQL script file.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was, previously when i used enter mysql cli and source the dump after giving `use thisdb` it used to fill the `thisdb` with the dump. However ever since we updated the mysql version we had to open the dump file and change the `use dumpfromsomeothersource` to `use thenewdb` within the dumpfile.