# Restore a .sql file

Tags: mysql, navicat

I have a MySQL dump (.sql file) which I want to restore.  I am trying to restore it using Navicat, but somehow I just can't do this.  Maybe I am missing some info here.  I have tried following the steps in this link
http://www.navicat.com/manual/online_manual/en/navicat/win_manual/DumpExecuteSQL.html
But the  Execute SQL File is grayed out.  Any idea of how to proceed?  I am at lost here.

Comment: Dunno about navicat but you can execute a sql file from the MySQL command line, E.g. [How to import an SQL file using the command line in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql)

Comment: @AlexK. You mean open the cmd and then try this :mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql ?

Comment: Yes. (If that doesn't work run it from the directory where the mysql executable is)

Comment: I don't get how this works.  Where will the database be restored?  And how do I make queries on it?

Comment: use following command : mysql -u username –-password=password database_name < file.sql

Comment: @KunalSurana: I don't get how this works. Where will the database be restored? And how do I make queries on it?

Comment: Do you have compelete dump of database in your .sql file ? if yes then run  above command to import everything.

Comment: @KunalSurana : I believe so, yes

Comment: Mysql is install on windows or linux

Comment: @KunalSurana :  OK. And how do I make queries on the restored database?

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncheck "Run multiple queries in each execution".

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the database is created first. After creating the database, right click on the database and select *Execute sql file*. After selecting this, you will get a popup window where you can select your sql file and click on *start*. Now all the data from the backup will be loaded in your database.