# MAMP: Importing Large Database into phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I'm on a Mac and I'm trying to import a 1.2GB database but phpMyAdmin limits the file to 32MiB. I understand there is a way to do this from the command line, but the answers I've found so far pertain to Windows and Linux. Any hints on how to do this on a Mac? Thanks in advance for your time,
Bill

Comment: You can increase the `upload_max_filesize` in your MAMP's php.ini file. As for running MySQL from the command line on your mac, it should be relatively the same as the Linux instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The Mac instructions are the same as the Linux ones; the only difference is how you get the the command line first.

Go to the Applications folder, then open up the Utilities folder. Run "Terminal.app" to get to the command line.

From there, you can use the normal MySQL command line tool, [as answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17666279/2385479) (and other places): `mysql -u username -p database_name < /path/to/file.sql`