# Importing sql file to MySQL

Tags: mysql, import

I have a sql file containing data that I want to import to a table on MySQL.

I know the dead easy way is to use a a management software like MySQL work bench and import it that way but I want to learn how to it by command line

I already have sftp the file to the root directly on my linux system but im unsure how to import the data from the .sql file to the table I have in my database.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql

Comment: What else did you try so far, did you search on google?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the file as input to the `mysql` command from the shell command prompt.

```
$ mysql -h servername -u username -p databasename < filename.sql
```

You will then be prompted for your password.

If you're already inside the `mysql` program, you can use its `source` command.

```
mysql> source filename.sql
```

Comment: I found away, I logged into mysql, use database name, and ran the following source name.sql and this populates my table I created

Comment: I thought you said you wanted to do it from the Linux command line.

Comment: Sorry that was an error on myside. I ment from the mysql line