# Import a MySQL table-definition dump using Spring's ResourceDatabasePopulator

Tags: java, mysql, spring

We hava a Spring test execution listener which imports dumped MySQL table definitions through Spring's `ResourceDatabasePopulator`:

```
public class DBSetupExecutionListener extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {
    ...

    @Override
    public synchronized void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) {
        ...
        // import the table definitions from a previously dumped file
        ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        populator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("some-table-definitions.sql"));
        populator.execute(dataSource);
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

The imported MySQL dump file does look like this (simplified):

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `someTable`;

CREATE TABLE `someTable`(
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `other_table_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   ...
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   KEY `FK_OTHERTABLE_ID`(`other_table_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `FK_OTHERTABLE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`other_table_id`) REFERENCES `otherTable`(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `otherTable`;

CREATE TABLE `otherTable`(
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

...

/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

While importing the dump via [command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql) works without any issues, ResourceDatabasePopulator is ignoring the preprocessor instructions and therefore failing on creating the referencing table first before the actual referenced table is created. Changing the order of the table definitions does solve the issue but is a bit tedious for multiple tables though - especially when you dump the current table definition to a file.

As importing dumped SQL table definitions is a quite common task IMO I guess I'm doing something wrong here. Is there a way to tell `ResourceDatabasePopulator` to respect the preprocessing instructions and therefore to prevent foreign key checks while executing the script?

Comment: Nope, unless you build your own implementation for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the advice of @M.Deinum and implemented my own version of a `ResourceDatabasePopulator`. Due to the limited scope of the members and the absence of any getters to retrieve these fields, there is unfortunately some copy&pasting from the original `ResourceDatabasePopulator` implementation. This class was definitely not designed for supporting subclassing ...

Below is the current solution which is working for me in my use case. It is not perfect and probably tailored towards MySQL statements but at least it gets the job done.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Map;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.UncategorizedScriptException;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

/**
 * Populates, initializes, or cleans up a database using SQL scripts defined in
 * external resources.
 * <p>
 * This implementation will clean up a given script by removing comments and processing instructions
 * contained in the script and perform a table reordering based on defined foreign keys in a
 * best-effort attempt.
 *
 * <ul>
 * <li>Call {@link #addScript} to add a single SQL script location.
 * <li>Call {@link #addScripts} to add multiple SQL script locations.
 * <li>Consult the setter methods in this class for further configuration options.
 * <li>Call {@link #populate} or {@link #execute} to initialize or clean up the
 * database using the configured scripts.
 * </ul>
 *
 * @author Keith Donald
 * @author Dave Syer
 * @author Juergen Hoeller
 * @author Chris Beams
 * @author Oliver Gierke
 * @author Sam Brannen
 * @author Chris Baldwin
 * @author Roman Vottner
 *
 * @since 3.0
 * @see DatabasePopulatorUtils
 * @see ScriptUtils
 */
public class OrderedResourceDatabasePopulator extends ResourceDatabasePopulator {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

  protected String sqlScriptEncoding;

  /**
   * Construct a new {@code OrderedResourceDatabasePopulator} with default settings.
   */
  public OrderedResourceDatabasePopulator() {
    /* no-op */
  }

  /**
   * Construct a new {@code OrderedResourceDatabasePopulator} with default settings
   * for the supplied scripts.
   * 
   * @param scripts the scripts to execute to initialize or clean up the database
   *                (never {@code null})
   */
  public OrderedResourceDatabasePopulator(Resource... scripts) {
    this();
    setScripts(cleanResource(scripts));
  }

  /**
   * Construct a new {@code OrderedResourceDatabasePopulator} with the supplied values.
   *
   * @param continueOnError flag to indicate that all failures in SQL should be logged but not cause
   *                        a failure
   * @param ignoreFailedDrops flag to indicate that a failed SQL {@code DROP} statement can be
   *                          ignored
   * @param sqlScriptEncoding the encoding for the supplied SQL scripts; may be {@code null} or
   *                           <em>empty</em> to indicate platform encoding
   * @param scripts the scripts to execute to initialize or clean up the database (never {@code
   *                null})
   */
  public OrderedResourceDatabasePopulator(boolean continueOnError, boolean ignoreFailedDrops,
                                          String sqlScriptEncoding, Resource... scripts) {

    super(continueOnError, ignoreFailedDrops, sqlScriptEncoding, scripts);
  }

  /**
   * Add a script to execute to initialize or clean up the database.
   *
   * @param script the path to an SQL script (never {@code null})
   */
  @Override
  public void addScript(Resource script) {
    super.addScript(cleanResource(script)[0]);
  }

  /**
   * Add multiple scripts to execute to initialize or clean up the database.
   * 
   * @param scripts the scripts to execute (never {@code null})
   */
  @Override
  public void addScripts(Resource... scripts) {
    super.addScripts(cleanResource(scripts));
  }

  /**
   * Set the scripts to execute to initialize or clean up the database, replacing any previously 
   * added scripts.
   * 
   * @param scripts the scripts to execute (never {@code null})
   */
  @Override
  public void setScripts(Resource... scripts) {
    super.setScripts(cleanResource(scripts));
  }

  /**
   * Specify the encoding for the configured SQL scripts, if different from the platform encoding.
   * 
   * @param sqlScriptEncoding the encoding used in scripts; may be {@code null} or empty to indicate
   *                          platform encoding
   * 
   * @see #addScript(Resource)
   */
  @Override
  public void setSqlScriptEncoding(String sqlScriptEncoding) {
    super.setSqlScriptEncoding(sqlScriptEncoding);
    this.sqlScriptEncoding = StringUtils.hasText(sqlScriptEncoding) ? sqlScriptEncoding : null;
  }

  private Resource[] cleanResource(Resource... scripts) {
    List<Resource> cleaned = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Resource script : scripts) {
      EncodedResource encodedScript = new EncodedResource(script, this.sqlScriptEncoding);

      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(encodedScript.getReader())) {
        String line;

        // parse script
        Map<String, Table> tables = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Table curTable = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
          if (!line.startsWith("#") && !line.startsWith("/*")) {
            line = line.replaceAll("`", "");
            String lowerCaseLine = line.toLowerCase();

            // parse table definitions
            if (lowerCaseLine.startsWith("drop table") || "".equals(line.trim())) {
              if (curTable != null) {
                curTable = null;
              }
              continue;
            }

            curTable = parseTable(line, tables, curTable);
          }
        }

        // check the order of table definitions and reorder them to ensure referenced tables are
        // defined before table specifying the foreign key
        Map<String, Table> orderedTables = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        List<Table> backlog = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String tableName : tables.keySet()) {
          // check for available foreign key definitions
          List<String> referencedTables = tables.get(tableName).getReferencedTables();
          // if no foreign keys are defined in the table we can add the table to the current set
          if (referencedTables.isEmpty()) {
            orderedTables.put(tableName, tables.get(tableName));
            processBacklog(backlog, orderedTables);
            continue;
          }

          // foreign keys are defined. If any of the referenced tables is not yet in the set move it
          // to the backlog table and try it later
          boolean dependenciesAvailable = true;
          for (String dependency : referencedTables) {
            if (!orderedTables.containsKey(dependency)) {
              backlog.add(tables.get(tableName));
              dependenciesAvailable = false;
              break;
            }
          }

          // if all referred tables are available in the set add the current table also to the
          // ordered set
          if (dependenciesAvailable) {
            orderedTables.put(tableName, tables.get(tableName));
            processBacklog(backlog, orderedTables);
            continue;
          }

          // probe tables kept in the backlog again
          processBacklog(backlog, orderedTables);
        }

        while (!backlog.isEmpty()) {
          processBacklog(backlog, orderedTables);
        }

        ArrayList<Table> reverse = new ArrayList<>(orderedTables.values());
        ListIterator<Table> reverseIter = reverse.listIterator(reverse.size());
        sb.append("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ");
        int originalSize = sb.length();
        while (reverseIter.hasPrevious()) {
          if (sb.length() > originalSize) {
            sb.append(", ");
          }
          sb.append(reverseIter.previous().getName());
        }
        sb.append(";\n\n");

        for (Table table : orderedTables.values()) {
          sb.append(table.getCreateStatement()).append("\n");
        }

      } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new UncategorizedScriptException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
      }

      if (LOG.isTraceEnabled()) {
        LOG.trace("SQL script after cleaning: \n{}", sb.toString());
      }
      Resource cleanedResource = new ByteArrayResource(sb.toString().getBytes());
      cleaned.add(cleanedResource);
    }

    return cleaned.toArray(new Resource[cleaned.size()]);
  }

  private Table parseTable(String line, Map<String, Table> tables, Table curTable) {
    String lowerCaseLine = line.toLowerCase();
    if (lowerCaseLine.startsWith("create table")) {
      String name = line.substring("create table ".length(), line.indexOf("(")).trim();
      curTable = new Table(name);
      tables.put(name, curTable);
    } else if (curTable != null) {
      if (lowerCaseLine.contains("primary key")) {
        curTable.setPrimaryKey(line);
      } else if (lowerCaseLine.contains("unique key")) {
        curTable.addUniqueKey(line);
      } else if (lowerCaseLine.contains("foreign key")) {
        curTable.addForeignKey(line);
      } else if (lowerCaseLine.contains(" key ")) {
        curTable.addIndex(line);
      } else if (lowerCaseLine.contains(" charset=") || lowerCaseLine.contains("engine=")) {
        curTable.setMetaData(line);
      } else {
        curTable.addColumn(line);
      }
    }
    return curTable;
  }

  private void processBacklog(List<Table> backlog, Map<String, Table> orderedTables) {
    Iterator<Table> iter = backlog.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      Table table = iter.next();
      boolean allDependenciesAvailable = true;
      for (String dependency : table.getReferencedTables()) {
        if (!orderedTables.containsKey(dependency)) {
          allDependenciesAvailable = false;
        }

        if (allDependenciesAvailable) {
          orderedTables.put(table.getName(), table);
          iter.remove();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private class Table {

    private final String name;
    private List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
    private String primaryKey;
    private List<String> uniqueKeys = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> indices = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> foreignKeys = new ArrayList<>();
    private String metaData;

    public Table(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    String getName() {
      return this.name;
    }

    void addColumn(String column) {
      this.columns.add(column);
    }

    void setPrimaryKey(String primaryKey) {
      this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
    }

    void addUniqueKey(String uniqueKey) {
      this.uniqueKeys.add(uniqueKey);
    }

    void addIndex(String index) {
      this.indices.add(index);
    }

    void addForeignKey(String foreignKey) {
      this.foreignKeys.add(foreignKey);
    }

    List<String> getReferencedTables() {
      List<String> referencedTables = new ArrayList<>();
      for (String foreignKey : foreignKeys) {
        int start = foreignKey.toLowerCase().indexOf("references ") + "references ".length();
        String table = foreignKey.substring(start, foreignKey.indexOf(" ", start));
        referencedTables.add(table);
      }
      return referencedTables;
    }

    void setMetaData(String metaData) {
      this.metaData = metaData;
    }

    String getCreateStatement() {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append("CREATE TABLE ").append(this.name).append(" (");
      for (String column : this.columns) {
        sb.append("\n");
        sb.append("  ").append(column);
      }
      if (null != primaryKey) {
        sb.append("\n");
        sb.append("  ").append(this.primaryKey);
      }
      if (!uniqueKeys.isEmpty()) {
        for (String uniqueKey : uniqueKeys) {
          sb.append("\n");
          sb.append("  ").append(uniqueKey);
        }
      }
      if (!indices.isEmpty()) {
        for (String index : indices) {
          sb.append("\n");
          sb.append("  ").append(index);
        }
      }
      if (!foreignKeys.isEmpty()) {
        for (String foreignKey : foreignKeys) {
          sb.append("\n");
          sb.append("  ").append(foreignKey);
        }
      }
      sb.append("\n");
      if (metaData == null || !metaData.contains(")")) {
        sb.append(") ");
      }
      if (metaData != null) {
        sb.append(metaData);
      }
      sb.append("\n");

      return sb.toString();
    }
  }
}
```

This populator will first clean the given scripts from any unwanted characters, comments or processing instructions and then build up a virtual table structure in order to sort tables that are target of a foreign reference before the ones declaring the foreign reference. Once the table definitions got virtualized, the populator will recreate the script by first adding a `DROP TABLE` statement for each table in reverese order of the virtual model and afterwards adding the `CREATE TABLE` statements in the calculated order.

Note that this version does not yet support other SQL commands (like `INSERT`, ...) contained in the script. If this is needed feel free to customize this code to your liking.

In order to make use of reordered SQL scripts simply replace `ResourceDatabasePopulator` with `OrderedResourceDatabasePopulator`

```
@Override
public synchronized void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) {
    ...
    // import the table definitions from a previously dumped file
    ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new OrderedResourceDatabasePopulator();
    populator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("some-table-definitions.sql"));
    populator.execute(dataSource);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple, albeit slightly hacky, solution could be to override the block comment start delimiter to something that will never occur in the script, e.g:

```
ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
populator.setBlockCommentStartDelimiter("EXECUTE_COMMENTS_PLZ");
```