# How to import database through terminal ubuntu?

Tags: database, ubuntu, terminal

I want to import database in phpmyadmin mysql from terminal ubuntu. Can anybody give me command to insert such large size database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import an SQL file using the command line in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I got my answer.

First of all, write into termial as

```
$ mysql -u (username) -p (password)
Example, $ mysql -u root -p root
```

then, it will be like

```
mysql> use db_name;
 Example, mysql> use my_database
```

then enter your source path.

```
mysql> source backup-file.sql;
Example, mysql> use /home/kazim_noorani/database_file.sql
```