# PHPMyAdmin Internal Server Error - Internal Error or Misconfiguration

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin

I have the latest MAMP Pro and it woks great most of the time.

Besides other development activities I do WordPress Core and Plugin updates on 22 websites. I always run the updates on a local (MAMP) version before updating the Live site to verify that there are no conflicts that might break the website. Every couple of months I refresh my local copy of the website.

5 out of the 22 sites error when importing the database. These aren't large sites so SQL file size isn't the issue.

Here's the error message I get from PHPMyAdmin:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, you@example.com and inform
>   them of the time the error occured, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

There was only this error in the Apache Log (no errors in MySQL or PHP logs.)

> [Sun Feb 26 11:13:47 2017] [error] [client ::1] FastCGI: comm with
>   server "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php5.6.28.fcgi" aborted: idle
>   timeout (30 sec) [Sun Feb 26 11:13:47 2017] [error] [client ::1]
>   FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server
>   "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php5.6.28.fcgi"

I was wondering if this is an issue with MySQL Version mismatch. The live sites are running Version 5.7.15 but MAMP Pro is back on 5.6.34. Other websites with the same version import OK, but these 5 sites do not.

I'm reasonably competent, but no expert when dealing with server issues. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
David R

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with mysql. Btw the error message is from apache, not from phpmyadmin.

Comment: These messages appear in the Apache log exactly as PHPMyAdmin errors out of an import.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import an SQL file using the command line in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql)