# Import file into MariaDB on Windows WSL

Tags: mariadb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to import a file into MariaDB on my WSL Subsystem on Windows, following this thread: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql`

I have copied the `.sql` file to my home directory in WSL and hence my command looks like this:

```
$ mysql -u root -p sampledatabase < ~/databases/Datanmodell_init.sql
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using 
password: YES)
```

What am I doing wrong?

merci A

Comment: Did you try with a normal user?

Comment: I have tried it with and without `sudo` - no difference.

Comment: The password is for MySQL's "root", not the OS.

Comment: @Rick what do you mean by that?

Comment: The error message says you used the wrong password.