# Bash: mysqlimport command to write to database without prompt

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm trying to restore the empty DB for mydb table but the syntax of `mysqlimport` doesn't seem to be straight forward. I had earlier created the file emptyDbs when doing a mysqldump.

```
mysqlimport mydb/var/tmp/emptyDbs
```

Comment: You simple need to call, `mysql` command.

Comment: Still a problem.. echo "mysqlimport mydb  /var/tmp/emptyDbs" | mysql statsdb
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqlimport /var/tmp/emptyDbs' at line 1

Comment: Use `mysql < file_to_import.sql`

Comment: You could refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql for more details

Answer (score 1):

```
 mysql statsdb < /var/tmp/emptyDbs
```