# import dabase inside maria db

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I have a problem.
I try to import a db inside maria but I have an error.

Where is the problem

> mysqldump --user=zzzzzzz --password=xxxxxxx aaaaaaaaaa <
>   /var/www/xxxxxxxxxxx.org/web/data-dump.sql
>
> ```
> -- MySQL dump 10.16  Distrib 10.1.37-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
> --
> -- Host: localhost    Database: xxxxxxxxx
> -- ------------------------------------------------------
> -- Server version 10.1.37-MariaDB-0+deb9u1
>
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
> /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
> /*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
> /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
> /*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
> /*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
> /*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
> /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;
>
> /*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
> /*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
> /*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
> /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
> /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
> /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
> /*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
> ```

Comment: whats the error??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import an SQL file using the command line in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysqldump` to dump; use `mysql` to import.

```
mysqldump ... > foo.sql
mysql     ... < foo.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

For Import, You should use `mysql` command not `mysqldump`:

```
mysql --user=zzzzzzz --password=xxxxxxx aaaaaaaaaa < /var/www/xxxxxxxxxxx.org/web/data-dump.sql
```

Comment: import, not export

Comment: I have updated the code. For Import it should be simply `mysql`.