# mysqldump command export and import table, views, function, procedures

Tags: mysql

For exporting I tried,

```
mysqldump -u root DB1 -R > E:\Java\AkshayProject\Dump\DBbackup.sql
```

It worked !

For importing I tried,

```
mysqldump -u root DB2 -R < E:\Java\AkshayProject\Dump\DBbackup.sql
```

Result :

> ### -- MySQL dump 10.16  Distrib 10.1.38-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64)
>
> -- Host: localhost    Database: demo
>
> ---
>
> -- Server version       10.1.38-MariaDB
>
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
>   /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
>   /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
>   /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */; /*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE
>   */; /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */; /*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */; /*!40014 SET
>   @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
>   /*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE,
>   SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */; /*!40111 SET
>   @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
>
> --
>   -- Dumping routines for database 'db2'
>   -- /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;
>
> /*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */; /*!40014 SET
>   FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */; /*!40014 SET
>   UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */; /*!40101 SET
>   CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */; /*!40101 SET
>   CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */; /*!40101 SET
>   COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */; /*!40111 SET
>   SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
>
> -- Dump completed on 2019-10-11 21:22:56

I checked, nothing is imported in DB2

How to import database with all tables, views, procedures and functions?

Comment: Check the SQL dump for `USE DB1` ?   `CREATE TABLE DB1.<table_name> .... `   things?

Comment: ... as it should be not possible that `mysqldump -u root DB1 -R > E:\Java\AkshayProject\Dump\DBbackup.sql` command work and the second  `mysqldump -u root DB2 -R > E:\Java\AkshayProject\Dump\DBbackup.sql`  ..  So most likely there as `DB1` database references used in the import?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I import an SQL file using the command line in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-do-i-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql)

Comment: .. also i do not understand the result ??? Do you mean you got a error when running `mysqldump -u root DB2 -R < E:\Java\AkshayProject\Dump\DBbackup.sql` ?

Comment: @nbk Other answers only talks about importing tables. Their methods don't work for importing and exporting views, functions, procedures etc.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Whatever output I got on command prompt, I've mentioned it in question description. When I checked database DB2, it was empty. Nothing was imported in it

Comment: I opened the exported file using mysql workbench. It imported all tables, views, functions and procedures when I run that file in mysql workbench. How can I do it using command line?

Comment: There are a lot of options for mysqldumpfor at least routines is necessary see all options for mysqldump https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: why following command not working?

mysqldump -u root DB2 -R < E:\Java\AkshayProject\Dump\DBbackup.sql