# How to reference a .sql file not in the same directory as mysql.exe with source command

Tags: mysql, cmd

The reference material says to use the source command like this:

```
mysql> source file_name
```

My .sql file is in a different directory, so I tried it a few ways:

Like this:

```
mysql> source c:\Users\Username\SQLdumps\sqlscript.sql;
```

and:

```
mysql> source 'c:\Users\Username\SQLdumps\sqlscript.sql';
```

and:

```
mysql> source "c:\Users\Username\SQLdumps\sqlscript.sql";
```

and

```
mysql> source \Users\Username\SQLdumps\sqlscript.sql;
```

and

```
mysql> source "\Users\Username\SQLdumps\sqlscript.sql";
```

In every case I get an error message that says to check the manual for syntax to use near source. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mofi you were right, the slashes were the wrong direction (I copy/pasted from windows explorer). But it needed to be without quotes. So the right way is: source c:/Users/Username/SQLdumps/sqlscript.sql;  If you want to put that as an answer I will choose it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I import an SQL file using the command line in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-do-i-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql)

Comment: Nbk no, I saw that one when I was looking for a solution but it doesn't address how to write the file name if it's in a different directory. See my comments above; Mofi solved it.

Comment: I think it is a security precaution. iuse the mysql -uxyz -pvcd < sql . I don't see another option, if you want to import the file or you copy the executable instead of teh sql file

Comment: No, like I said I was able to make this work just fine, by switching the directions of the slashes. It was a simple fix.