# Is it possible to run completely built wordpress site locally for development?

Tags: php, wordpress, development-environment, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a completely live eCommerce WordPress website, I want to run the code locally so that I can debug the code. If it's not possible, is there any other best approach in this case? I want to make development easier. Right now after every code change I need to update through FileZila and refresh staging pages to see the modifications and its difficult to debug too.

Comment: There are so many tutorials and guides about this, did you try searching?  If your use case is somehow different, you need to explain specifically what you need, what you tried, what happened, etc.  Check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have a wordpress website. I wanted to make modifications to the page templates. I would like to know the best practice for such a development process as a developer that I should know

Answer (score 1):

1. Install local development: https://github.com/wordpress/wordpress-develop
2. Copy your themes and plugin folder to development.
3. Migrate database.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm having a huge database so its not working for me to make a local copy of the same. What should I do in this case ?

Comment: @NithinSuresh
You just need to import db via commandline: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-do-i-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

1. Downloaded local environment:
   https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html
2. Increase file size for local environment:
   https://w3guy.com/fix-size-xampp-installation-folder-size/
3. Install WordPress:
   https://www.wordpress.org
4. Install themes and plugins

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm having a huge database so its not working for me to make a local copy of the same. What should I do in this case ?