# MariaDB create database via CLI

Tags: mariadb, command-line-interface

How do I issue commands to MariaDB via the CLI without actually jumping into the interactive use mode?

I know I can type `mysql` which will then jump me into the interactive mode where I can write SQL commands like `CREATE DATABASE dbname;` and then exit to go back to the regular terminal.

However I'd like to skip that and do something like `mysql 'CREATE DATABASE dbname;'` all in one line.

Comment: Have two "terminals" running.

Comment: @RickJames how would that help?

Comment: Only trivially -- You would not need to go in and out of mariadb.

Comment: The canonical question (MariaDB's and MySQL's should be sufficiently compatible): *[How do I import an SQL file using the command line in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/)* (62 answers (incl. deleted))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I import an SQL file using the command line in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-do-i-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mysql --help | grep "\-execute"
```

Output:

> -e, --execute=name  Execute command and quit

So to create a database with command line client, you just need to execute

```
mysql -uuser -p -e"CREATE DATABASE dbname"
```

You can also concatenate several SQL statements, e.g.

```
mysql -uuser -p -e"CREATE DATABASE dbname;SHOW DATABASES"
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the commands that you want executed into a text file (optionally with a file extension of .sql) then, from the command line, do `mysql -uuser -p < yourtextfile.sql` to have all of the commands in the file executed.

Comment: Is it possible to swap the text file for a quoted string like `mysql -user -p < 'create database dbname;'` ?

Comment: Have you tried it? It doesn't work for me and you would still need to interact with it to supply the password.