# How to add a mysql dump to a laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-8

I have a laravel project running inside docker. What I want to do is connect to a new database from a sql dump (.sql file).

What I did is modify the .env file and the config/database.php file as specified by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel).

So, how could I create the new database from the dump file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I import an SQL file using the command line in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-do-i-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

If u want to create a database from the dump file, you can do it with this UNIX command line.

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

OR via MySQL command line.

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE database_name;
mysql> use database_name;
mysql> source file.sql;
```

OR connect your database with your favorite database tool and use import option.

Anyway, your question has nothing to do with Laravel.