# How do I upload/import .sql file into mysql using cmd?

Tags: mysql, cmd

cmd command

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -u root -p comedy portal < user.sql
```

I am using this command to import sql file in db but it is giving me error

```
user                              root
safe-updates                      FALSE
i-am-a-dummy                      FALSE
connect-timeout                   0
max-allowed-packet                16777216
net-buffer-length                 16384
select-limit                      1000
max-join-size                     1000000
secure-auth                       FALSE
show-warnings                     FALSE
plugin-dir                        (No default value)
default-auth                      (No default value)
binary-mode                       FALSE
connect-expired-password          FALSE
```

Comment: Duplicate Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-do-i-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql

Comment: yes  i have already read the instructions but still its not working for me

Comment: What's the error you're getting? "Not working" doesn't tell us anything about your problem.

Comment: There shouldn't be a space between the -p and the password.

Comment: there is no pswrd and above i mentioned the error

Comment: If there's no password then what is `comedy` in the string above? Have you got a database name with spaces in it?

Comment: And I don't see any error, you've just shown us a load of options

Comment: yes comedy portal is the name of db

Comment: Name with spaces in is always a bad idea. But since you're there now, try putting it in single quote marks, or in backticks, so mysql knows it's not two separate fields in the command

Comment: okk thank you. Let me  give it a try

Comment: duplication : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-do-i-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql