# how to convert a sql file dumped from plesk to excel or mysql?

Tags: mysql, plesk

how I can convert a SQL file dumped from Plesk to excel or MySQL by software without installing SQL server management on windows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I import an SQL file using the command line in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-do-i-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

I found this for a MySQL import via Command Line, without SSMS:

```
  mysql -u username -p new_database < data-dump.sql
```

here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-import-and-export-databases-in-mysql-or-mariadb

Answer (score 0):

In Plesk:

1: Go to your DB page [plesk DB page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv9mB.png)

2: Hit phpMyAdmin

In phpMyAdmin:

1: Hit export [phpMyAdmin nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTS3s.png)

2: Go down to where it say "Format" and change it to the format of your choosing [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXrq3.png)

3: Click on "Go"

Hope this helps,

Ethan Lindsey