# How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive join

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

I have a problem getting markup_category value.

I have to calculate product retail prices.

`retail_price = price + (price / 100 * markup_category)`

So when product category has markup_category it is not problem. But sometimes category does not have this value and then parent category markup must be used. I can not take its value in one query.

Table structure:

| category_id | parent_id | markup_category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 168 | 0 | 50.00 |
| 1048 | 168 | 0.00 |
| 1092 | 1048 | 0.00 |

And when I try to do something like: (took query here: [How do I import an SQL file using the command line in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-do-i-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql))

`SELECT category_id, @pv:=parent_id AS parent_id, markup_category FROM cscart_categories JOIN (SELECT @pv:=1092) tmp WHERE category_id=@pv`

I get only this as result:

| category_id | parent_id | markup_category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1048 | 168 | 0.00 |
| 1092 | 1048 | 0.00 |

How to get first category with `markup_category > 0` ?

Comment: Excuse me, took query here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query

Comment: you mean that question and its answers answered your question?

Comment: @ysth No, just firstly added incorrect link to original question. I still have problem to get markup_category

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: @ysth 10.3.32-MariaDB

Comment: MariaDB 10.3.32 supports [window functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions-overview/)

Comment: @FanoFN thanks. You helped me. But now I don't know how to join it to query which select product prices :)

Comment: That's ok. I'm glad you've found solution. For different issue, you should post a new question and mark your answer here as "accepted".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helped me in this case

```
WITH RECURSIVE markup_categories AS (
    SELECT 
        category_id, 
        parent_id, 
        markup_category 
    FROM 
        cscart_categories 
    WHERE 
        category_id = 1092 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        c2.category_id, 
        c2.parent_id, 
        c2.markup_category 
    FROM 
        cscart_categories AS c2, 
        markup_categories AS mc 
    WHERE 
        c2.category_id = mc.parent_id
) 
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    markup_categories
```