# Is there a way to backup Data from a cpanel database to import it on a localhost database?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Well, I'm doing a website for a company, and I'm working on different steps, lets's say, first I upload some part of the functional website while I work on future sections.
The thing is that I'm creating more tables and columns on the localhost database.

What I need to do is to copy all the Data from the cPanel phpMyAdmin Database, insert it into the new DB, and then re-upload the new Database on that server without losing the information.

This is because every time I upload the Database to the Hosting it resets the values of the tables.

I don't know how not to lose that information, thanks for reading, and sorry if you don't understand something but I'm not an English native speaker.

(I'm using MySQL for the Database Management).

Comment: just click export in phpmyadmin

Comment: But how can import that data that i export on the new database? @0nepeop1e

Comment: the phpmyadmin will export the data as sql file which basically consists of sql queries to recreate tables and insert data, so you just execute the sql file with your local database, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-do-i-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for the answer and for the help, one last question, I'm going to load that information on a new database which will contain probably more tables and more columns, importing that SQL will not delete my changes right?

Comment: no, unless the table is same name with those in the exported sql

Comment: ok thank you so much :)